# Performance Problems When Preparing Statement Multiple Times

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, postgresql, prepared-statement

I've got a PHP application that uses PDO with prepared statements, both in PostgreSQL and MySQL, and I'm wondering if there's a performance hit when preparing the exact same statements each time before executing it.

In pseudo-code, an example would be something like:

```
for ($x=0; $x<100; $x++) {
    $obj = PDO::prepare("SELECT x,y,z FROM table1 WHERE x=:param1 AND y=:param2");
    $obj->execute(array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2));
}
```

As opposed to preparing once and executing multiple times:

```
$obj = PDO::prepare("SELECT x,y,z FROM table1 WHERE x=:param1 AND y=:param2");
for ($x=0; $x<100; $x++) {
    $obj->execute(array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2));
}
```

I've searched for this question many times, but can't seem to find a reference to it in PHP, nor PostgreSQL, nor MySQL.

Comment: I can't believe you didn't find anything on the topic, because multiple execution advertised as a killer-feature (which actually isn't but anyway)

Comment: One of the things that prompted me to ask this question was that a colleague indicated PHP+MySQL had some limitation where too many prepared statements would cause the driver (or PHP, or maybe the server) to die strangely or reset the connection. Doing a prepare+execute every time (versus one prepare, multiple execute) is a design flaw in [one of my libraries](https://github.com/crazedsanity/cs-webapplibs/blob/master/cs_phpDB.class.php) that I just recently found.

Comment: Did he happen to define "too many" in some at least rough numbers?

Comment: I believe it was in the tens of thousands, possibly 65k. To me, hitting that would require some extra poor coding, as running 65k queries within a single page indicates a very profound need for optimization.

Comment: I believe I found a way to fix this particular problem in the library (https://github.com/crazedsanity/cs-webapplibs): either a new method that accepts a PDOStatement object (instead of the query), or allowing the "run_query()" method to accept either the object or a string.  I think a second method would be better, as it seems cleaner, allows type-hinting, and maintains backwards-compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it somewhat defeats the purpose of using prepared statements. Preparing allows the DB to pre-parse the query and get things ready for execution. When you do execute the statement, the DB simply slips in the values you're providing and performs the last couple steps.

When you prepare inside a loop like that, all of the preparation work gets thrown out and re-done each time. What you should have is:

```
$obj = PDO::prepare("SELECT x,y,z FROM table1 WHERE x=:param1 AND y=:param2");
for ($x=0; $x<100; $x++) {
    $obj->execute(array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2));
}
```

prepare once, execute many times.

Comment: I already understood this (in theory).  I'm looking for any concrete information that there's an actual impact on performance.  I've got [code](https://github.com/crazedsanity/cs-webapplibs/blob/master/cs_phpDB.class.php) that has no way of determining if a query has been previously prepared: I'm considering refactoring it, but I'd like a bit more information on the benefits of doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a performance hit.  The prepare step has to parse the SQL string and analyze it to decide which tables it needs to access and how it's going to do that (which indexes to use, etc.).  So if you prepare() once before the loop begins, and then just execute() inside the loop, this is a cost savings.

This is an example of a more general programming principle:  **you shouldn't put code inside a loop if the result of that code is the same for every iteration of the loop.**

PS: You shouldn't use `PDO::prepare()`, you should create a PDO object and call `$pdo->prepare()`.

PPS: You should also check the return value of prepare() and execute().  They return **false** on errors.  Or else configure PDO to throw exceptions on error.

Comment: As previously stated, it's pseudo-code. Here's [the actual code](https://github.com/crazedsanity/cs-webapplibs/blob/master/cs_phpDB.class.php). Basically, once the object is created, the "run_query" method is called and uses PDO::prepare each time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not doing this? It will of course execute solver. But since no connection to DB or heavy calculation is done at preparation (since query is short), speed change will be insignificant, but that`s a bad style.

```
$obj = PDO::prepare("SELECT x,y,z FROM table1 WHERE x=:param1 AND y=:param2");
for ($x=0; $x<100; $x++) {
    $obj->execute(array('param1'=>$param1, 'param2'=>$param2));
}
```

Comment: I've attempted to make the question as concise as possible to avoid getting lost in the implementation details.  [Here is the code](https://github.com/crazedsanity/cs-webapplibs/blob/master/cs_phpDB.class.php).