# Insert multiple data into different tables in a single transaction

Tags: php, pdo, php-7.4, bindvalue

This has nothing to do with Frameworks because it is an external project, I am currently developing to learn, some things about database management or how databases behave...

I need help with some php and PDO... Previously I dev this script:

```php
<?php

class DataBaseManager
{
    public function GetData($query, $user, $pass)
    {
        try {
            $db_result = [];
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $user, $pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            reset($query);
            $db_name = key($query);
            $conn->exec('USE ' . $db_name);
            $db_result['r'] = $conn->query($query[$db_name], PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $count = $db_result['r']->rowCount();
            $db_result['c'] = $count;
            if (0 == $count) {
                $db_result['r'] = null;
            } elseif (1 == $count) {
                $db_result['r'] = $db_result['r']->fetch();
            }

            return $db_result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function DeleteData($query, $user, $pass)
    {
        try {
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $user, $pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            foreach ($query as $db_name => $query_arr) {
                $conn->exec('USE ' . $db_name);
                foreach ($query_arr as $key => $query_string) {
                    $conn->exec($query_string);
                    ++$ct;
                }
            }
            $conn->commit();
            $conn = null;

            return '<b>' . $ct . ' Records Deleted Successfully.</b>';
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $conn->rollback();
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function SetData($query, $user, $pass)
    {
        try {
            $db_result = [];
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test", $user, $pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $conn->beginTransaction();
            $conn->exec("set names utf8");
            $count = ['u' => 0, 'i' => 0];
            foreach ($query as $db_name => $query_arr) {
                $conn->exec('USE ' . $db_name);
                foreach ($query_arr as $key => $query_string) {
                    $cq = $conn->exec($query_string);
                    if (strpos($query_string, 'UPDATE') !== false) {
                        $count['u'] += $cq;
                    }
                    if (strpos($query_string, 'INSERT') !== false) {
                        $count['i'] += $cq;
                    }
                }
            }
            $conn->commit();
            $db_result['r'] = true;
            $db_result['t'] = 'Updates: ' . $count['u'] . ', Inserts: ' . $count['i'];

            return $db_result;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $conn->rollback();
            echo $e->getMessage();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to insert data by volumes in multiple tables in a single commit...

The idea of doing it that way is because if something fails I want it to be automatically rolled back in all table instances...

So I have a data structure in an array with the following content in my new class:

```php
$dbquery =[
        'test'=>[
            '0' =>[
                0 => 'INSERT INTO table_name_1(column1,column2) VALUES (?,?)', //mean it is the query
                1 =>[value11,value12],  // mean it is a row
                2 =>[value21,value22],  // mean it is a row
            ],
            '1' =>[
                0 => 'INSERT INTO table_name_2(column1,column2,column3,column4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', //mean it is the query
                1 =>[value11,value12,value13,value14], // mean it is a row
                2 =>[value21,value22,value23,value24], // mean it is a row
            ],
        ],
    ];
```

but i have my first try with bindValue, this is my new class mentioned:

```php
<?php

class DataBase
{
    private static ?DataBase $instance = null;

    public static function getInstance(): DataBase
    {
        if (!self::$instance instanceof self) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    private array $config;

    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->config = ['DB_HOST'=>'test','DB_NAME'=>'test','DB_USER'=>'test','DB_PASSWORD'=>''];
        $this->setConnection(new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->config['DB_HOST'] . ";dbname=" . $this->config['DB_NAME'], $this->config['DB_USER'], $this->config['DB_PASSWORD']));
    }

    private PDO $connection;

    /**
     * @return PDO
     */
    private function getConnection(): PDO
    {
        return $this->connection;
    }

    /**
     * @param PDO $connection
     */
    private function setConnection(PDO $connection): void
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function changeConnectionServer(string $host, string $db_name, string $user, string $password): void
    {
        $this->setConnection(new PDO("mysql:host=" . $host . ";dbname=" . $db_name, $user, $password));
    }

    private array $query;

    public function setDataBaseTarget(string $db_name)
    {
        if (empty($this->query)) {
            $this->query = [];
        }
        $this->query[$db_name] = [];
    }

    public function buildQuery(string $query)
    {
        if (empty($this->query)) {
            $this->query = [];
            $this->query[$this->config['DB_NAME']] = [];
        }
        $target = array_key_last($this->query);


        $this->query[$target][] = [$query];
    }

    public function addQueryData($data)
    {
        $target = array_key_last($this->query);
        $key = array_key_last($this->query[$target]);
        $this->query[$target][$key][] = $data;
    }

    private function getQuery(): array
    {
        return $this->query;
    }

    /**
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public function setData(): array
    {
        try {
            $time = -microtime(true);
            $con = $this->getConnection();
            $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $con->beginTransaction();
            $con->exec("set names utf8;");

            foreach ($this->getQuery() as $db_name => $query_arr) {
                $con->exec('USE `' . $db_name . '`;');
                $ct = 0;
                
                // on this section have proble with code and logic .... i dont know what i need to dev to insert the data
                
                foreach ($query_arr as $query_structure) {
                    foreach ($query_structure as $key => $raw) {
                        if ($key === 0) {
                            $ct++;
                            $stmt[$ct] = $con->prepare($raw);
                        } else {
                            if (is_array($raw)) {
                                $c = 0;
                                foreach ($raw as $value) {
                                    $c++;
                                    $stmt[$ct]->bindValue($c, $value, $this->getParamType($value));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $stmt[$ct]->execute();
                }
                
                //end section
                
            }



            //$con->commit();


            return true;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            
            $con->rollback();
            echo $e->getMessage();

            return false;
        }
    }

    private function getParamType($value)
    {
        if (is_int($value)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_INT;
        } elseif (is_bool($value)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
        } elseif (is_null($value)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_NULL;
        } elseif (is_string($value)) {
            return PDO::PARAM_STR;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

$db_handler = DataBase::getInstance();

$db_handler->buildQuery("INSERT INTO `client_list`(`email`,`mobile`) VALUES ('?','?');");
$db_handler->addQueryData(['mail1@test.com', '35634634636546']);
$db_handler->addQueryData(['mail2@test.com', '35634634636546']);
$db_handler->addQueryData(['mail3@test.com', '35634634636546']);
$db_handler->setData();
```

I can't figure out, develop the part that allows me to package everything in a single transaction... what I have is a `stm[]` ...

**Can someone help me with this development?**

Comment: Why are you storing the statement handles in an array? Just execute them on the spot and move on. Additionally, if the only thing that differs is the parameters, then you only need to call `prepare()` _once_ and then `bind()`/`execute()` as many times as you want.

Comment: @Sammitch *Why are you storing the statement ids in an array?*
to later be able to traverse and execute them within a single transaction.

Comment: @Sammitch *Just execute them on the spot and move on. Additionally, if the only thing that differs is the parameters, then you only need to call prepare() once and then bind()/execute() as many times as you want.* Yes, I understand what you're saying, but the problem is that I don't know how to organize my code in that section so that it runs by inserting each row... before reaching commit and not exploding XD

Comment: @Sammitch I guess what I'm doing is some rookie paraphernalia... but I'd like to try to make it work... the thing is, I'm trying to refactor the first class and this second one is as far as I've gotten... the first one executed querys directly from string... but it occurred to me to implement bindValue and now I'm here asking for help... sorry if i bother you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make heads or tails of all the things your class is doing, but here's a generalized version according to the bits that seem obvious:

```php
public function runMultipleQueries() {
    $dbh = $this->getConnection();
    // ... setup stuff
    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    try {
        foreach($this->queries as $query) {
            $stmt->prepare($query->queryString);
            $param_id = 1;
            foreach($query->params as $param) {
                $stmt->bindValue($param_id++, $param);
            }
            $stmt->execute();
        }
    } catch( \Exception $e ) {
        $dbh->rollback();
        throw $e;
        // IMO if you cannot fully/meaningfully recover, just re-throw and let it kill execution or be caught elsewhere where it can be
        // otherwise you're likely having to maintain a stack of if(foo() == false) { ... } wrappers
    }
    $dbh->commit();
}
```

Additionally, singleton DB classes have the drawbacks of both being limiting if you ever need a second DB handle, as well as boiling down to being global state, and subject to the same "spooky action at a distance" problems.

Consider using dependency inversion and feeding class dependencies in via constructor arguments, method dependencies via method arguments, etc. Eg:

```php
interface MyWrapperInterface {
    function setQueries(array $queries);
    function runQueries();
}

class MyDbWrapper implements MyWrapperInterface {
    protected $dbh;
    
    public function __construct(\PDO $dbh) {
        $this->dbh = $dbh;
    }
    
    public function setQueries(array $queries) { /* ... */ }
    public function runQueries() { /* ... */ }
}

class MyOtherThing {
    protected $db;
    
    public function __construct( MyWrapperInterface $db ) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    
    // ...
}

$wrapper1 = new MyDbWrapper(new PDO($connstr1, $options));
$wrapper2 = new MyDbWrapper(new PDO($connstr2, $options));

$thing1   = new MyOtherThing($wrapper1);
$thing2   = new MyOtherThing($wrapper2);
$thing1_2 = new MyOtherThing($wrapper1);

// etc
```

Comment: thanks, your version inserts one row at a time into the table... for each query; In my case, I am looking to be able to insert multiple rows; for each query, for this reason I have added an example of how the structure of the data array and query is being set up.

Comment: in my case I have not used the constructor to alter or change the connection to the database; I have instead created a `setConnection` method that allows me to switch to other connections, if the developer knows the credentials; I think the concept may differ... I don't know if this is wrong...

Comment: In my case I have not used the constructor either, nor inverse dependencies to feed the query; instead I have fed the rows of each query with the `addQueryData` method

Comment: I have a direct question, if I have a `$stmt->prepare()` how many times can I make it `$stmt->execute();` ??

Comment: I was thinking that I could create something like `beginTransaction; loop_query { prepare; loop_row{  loop_param{bindvalue;} execute; }} commit`

Comment: i find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18963657/20284348 I think this solves my previous question in the comments. I'll go test and come back with solutions, I hope so. Thank you very much for your contribution.

Comment: "One at a time" is irrelevant. You want it in a single transaction? That's what `beginTransaction()` and `commit()` are for. The answer you ultimately linked is ultimately the same as mine, but without explicitly starting the transaction or dealing with your multiple queries or multiple parameters.

Comment: of course i have make a script to get the goal thank you for your help... is the strat point to solve the point of view ...